# "fatal: bad object" when calling `git diff-tree` via groovy script?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, groovy

I would like to trigger a Jenkins build automatically when there is a push to Github. Moreover, based on the branch and modified files, I want to send a different function's args to the [SaltStack](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/saltstack-plugin) API and run on a different target VMs.

Here's my code at the *"Build environment" - "Inject environment variables to the build process"* step:

```
def map = [:]

println "env:"
def env = System.getenv()
env.each{
    println it
} 

println "envVarsMap:"
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
def envVarsMap = build.parent.builds[0].properties.get("envVars")
envVarsMap.each{
    println it
}

def envlist = [];
env.each() { k,v -> envlist.push( "$k=$v" ) }
envVarsMap.each { k,v -> envlist.push( "$k=$v" ) }

switch (envVarsMap['GIT_BRANCH']) {
    case "origin/development":
        map['DEPLOY_SERVER'] = "admin-dev-1,admin-staging-2"
        break
    case "origin/master":
        map['DEPLOY_SERVER'] = "admin-prod-1"
        break
}

println "GIT_COMMIT: ${envVarsMap['GIT_COMMIT']}"
println "WORKSPACE: ${envVarsMap['WORKSPACE']}"

def sout = new StringBuilder()
def serr = new StringBuilder()
proc1 = "git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${envVarsMap['GIT_COMMIT']}".execute(envlist, new File("${envVarsMap['WORKSPACE']}"))
proc1.waitForProcessOutput(sout, serr)
println "sout: $sout"
println "serr: $serr"
println "proc1: ${proc1.text}"
```

and the error:

```
GIT_COMMIT: c56ba02156bcf23598db09b9a02407316bf554dc
WORKSPACE: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-admin-app
sout: 
serr: fatal: bad object c56ba02156bcf23598db09b9a02407316bf554dc
```

Running this command manually as `jenkins` user on the CI server worked fine:

```
su - jenkins -s /bin/bash -c 'cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-admin-app; git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r c56ba02156bcf23598db09b9a02407316bf554dc'
package.json
```

So, my question is: Why do I got this error? How to reproduce this when running manually?

If the revision does not exist, we should get an "unknown revision" error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'c56ba02156bcf23598db09b9a02407316bf554dx': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: > If the revision does not exist, we should get an "unknown revision"

Not true, in your example `c56ba02156bcf23598db09b9a02407316bf554dx` is not a valid git commit hash, because it contains `x` character, try with any valid git commit hash and it will returns bad object error in output (replace `x` with an character from a-f).

Comment: OK, thanks. Upvoted. But the question is: why does it happened with `c56ba02156bcf23598db09b9a02407316bf554dc`?

Comment: I see a variable named WORKSPACE, but it's not at all clear that your current working directory has anything to do with this variable, and even if it is in your environment, it is not a variable that Git uses (Git uses $GIT_DIR and $GIT_WORK_TREE or `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` arguments).  Then again I don't know any of the details of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry.

We have a master and a few slave nodes.
By not checking *"Restrict where this project can be run"*, the build can be run on any node. The problem is the build was run on the slave:

> [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
>
> Building remotely on jenkins-slave-go-1 (golang) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-admin-app

but then the `git diff-tree` was checked on the master. I found out this by running `git log -1` instead.

So, I have to check *"Restrict where this project can be run"* and filled *master* as a label.